# How to create an MTLTexture from only Pixel Data and height and width?

Tags: bitmap, textures, metal

I think that using `MTKTextureLoader` and `MTLbuffer` is a kind of way, but I can't find details about this.

Comment: You don't even need to use `MTKTextureLoader` if the pixel data is already in a format supported by Metal. You can just create a texture of the appropriate size and call its [`replaceRegion:...` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515464-replace). If you can provide more detail about the type and layout of your pixel data, we can provide more specific help.

Comment: I solved it using the texture's replace method with a raw pointer pointing to the base address of the pixel data. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @exit/@warrenm can you please post a sample here? Or a link to the document/post you referred? New to Metal and Graphics. I have a 1D array with color codes of each pixel and other details. I can convert it to 2D or some other format as required.